# How to round the UITextField topRight and bottomLeft corners in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to round the corner of `UITextField` topLeft and bottomRight.

```
func conerRounderTextField(sides: CACornerMask) -> UITextField {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.backgroundColor = .white
    tf.clipsToBounds = true
    tf.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    tf.layer.maskedCorners = sides
    tf.layer.borderWidth = 1
    tf.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    return tf
}
```

and call the TextField like this:

```
private let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = Utillities().conerRounderTextField(sides: [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner])
    return tf
}()
```

By using this I'm getting the design what I want but the TextField is not working.

[image: design]

Can you help me?

Comment: text fields are not tapable ?

Comment: Yes it is not tapable @jawadAli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is working for me (Xcode 11.5):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func cornerRounderTextField(sides: CACornerMask) -> UITextField {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.backgroundColor = .white
        tf.clipsToBounds = true
        tf.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        tf.layer.maskedCorners = sides
        tf.layer.borderWidth = 1
        tf.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        return tf
    }
    
    private lazy var passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = cornerRounderTextField(sides: [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner])
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tf
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(passwordTextField)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            passwordTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            passwordTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            passwordTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
        ])
    }
}
```

(You can toggle the keyboard with cmd + k)